# Questions regarding sharing Google Drive store between devices

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I hava an iPad app where I store data using Core Data (sqlite store).

The app would be sharing the Core Data store between *authorized* users on a per-app/per store basis; in other words, one shop buys the app, and has several staff members with iPads who want to access the Core Data store on their iPad for that shop.  Other shops are have the same requirements, each shop having it's own unique Core Data store on a unique Google Drive, which would hopefully prevent one shop from looking/downloading another shop's data.

- is this possible?
- can someone please point me to the relevant docs that I need to get started with Google Drive API in my iOS app?
- is there a way that the app can synchronize the data between iPads on a per shop basis using Google Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put the Core Data in shop's Google Drive, there is a potential risk that the shop might accidentally delete or modify the Core Data, but anyway, this can be achieve like this:

In your app, ask for the shop account for [appropriate scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes), then store the credential in your service so later when staff members ask for the Core Data, you can delegate the shop account to grant shop's staff permission to access the Core Data. In the staff's Google Drive the file will appear in Shared With Me.

Maybe you should use another account to hold all the Core Data for all the shops, for example your service account. When one shop buys the app, your service creates a Core Data for the shop, then adds permission for only the shop. I suppose you want the Core Data to be readonly, so you can grant the reader permission for the shop. When shop staffs ask for the Core Data, you do the same for them.

Now the shop and staffs can access the Core Data, you will want it to be in specific folder, so it can be synchronised to shop or staff's local devices, in your case, their iPads. You can delegate the shop or staffs account to [create a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/folder) for them. Then [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) or [Patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch) the file's Parent to include the folder Id. The shops and shops' staffs will see the Core Data in the folder you create for them. This action will require a higher scope, say: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios

Hope it helps.